# How to retrieve from Sharedpreferences in AChartEngine Android

Tags: java, android, graph, sharedpreferences, achartengine

Can anyone provide me with an example of how to retrieve data stored in `SharedPreferences` files when creating an `AChartEngine` graph.

I am fairly new to android and Java. This my first ever call for help as I cannot find a solution.
My aim is to retrieve the string `userID` and update the graph title with it. The code I have so far shows the graph but not the `userID`.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class ProfileGraph extends Activity {

   private String userID;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       userID = sp.getString("USERID", "");
    }

    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        int[]x = {1,2,3};
        double[] y =  { 0.071, 0.09, 0.112 }; // y values!
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Dots"); 

        for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
        series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle(userID);

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
        return intent;

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you putting data into `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: `SharedPreferences sp =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);      
     SharedPreferences.Editor ed= sp.edit();
     ed.putInt("USERID", userID);     
     ed.commit(); `

Comment: This is done on a previous activity